# Solution verification: testing the convergence of a sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I am new to calculus, and I just wanted to check my reasoning re the following:

Given is the following series:

$$\sum n^s·e^{-n}, s \ge0$$

I was asked to prove that this series converges.

My reasoning was:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^s}{e^{(n+1)}}·\frac{e^n}{n^s}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^s}{en^s}=\frac {1}{e}$$

As $\frac {1}{e}<1$, the series converges.

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: It is correct i would have used root test it is a little quicker

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is definitely valid as an application of the ratio test.

One minor nitpick: it would've been more appropriate to indicate the index of summation, i.e.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \;\;\; \text{instead of} \;\;\; \sum$$

While it's okay to use the latter when the indices or the space over which you're summing is well understood, it's not necessarily true here, in my opinion. But this may well be just a personal issue since I struggled for a sec in figuring out which variable you were summing over.

*(For completeness' sake I assume it was something like the former, an infinite summation starting at some finite index, i.e. $0, 1,$ etc., and was a summation over $n$.)*

Comment: thank you! strangely enough, that's the way it appears in the exercise, so I didn't change it...

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. I mostly point it out because the main thing that could make the textbook's answer unusual is if it were understood be a finite sum (say from $n=1$ to $n=100$ or something). Of course that's probably not the case. It's probably just assumed it's infinite and starts at a finite index then, since a lot of these problems work like that. So there shouldn't be an issue I suppose.

Comment: (Post-script: Of course, it'll never hurt to check with your teacher/professor if you feel unsure. :p)